# , and they were fond of one another as friends who have come together in early youth "often are".

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar

[SOURCE](https://books.google.jo/books?id=xX3yCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT57&lpg=PT57&dq=and%20they%20were%20fond%20of%20one%20another%20as%20friends%20who%20have%20come%20together%20in%20early%20youth%20often%20are,%20in%20spite%20of%20the%20difference%20in%20their%20characters%20and%20tastes&source=bl&ots=VB8HjUEGk-&sig=6C-1ByjhiiMATGlkkyBt8Ad0RKg&hl=ar&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiC5J2s5PXVAhVGOhQKHS0uDWUQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=and%20they%20were%20fond%20of%20one%20another%20as%20friends%20who%20have%20come%20together%20in%20early%20youth%20often%20are%2C%20in%20spite%20of%20the%20difference%20in%20their%20characters%20and%20tastes&f=false) ANNA KARENINA

> - ,and they were fond of one another as friends who have come together in early youth often ***are***, in spite of the difference in their characters and tastes.

What is the purpose of "are" in this text?

Comment: as friends who have come together in early youth often are (fond of one another)—it's called **ellipsis**

Comment: Why "are" is used instead of were? @MvLog

Comment: cos it's a general statement

Answer (score 1):

> (the way) early youth often are

is just a statement about the state of society at that time. It is only used as a reference to the main dialog.
It might make more sense written this way:

> they were fond of one another as friends who have come together **in the way that early youth often *are***

where *are* means the way they act.